# connect to a server program using CSocket

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I've created this simple example program, but this doesn't work. it won't connect. any idea why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <afxsock.h>

void main()
{
    int lalala;
    CSocket mySocket;
    printf("%d\n", mySocket.Create());
    CString ipAddress = _T("127.0.0.1");
    lalala = mySocket.Connect(ipAddress, 3015);
    printf("%d", lalala);
    getchar();
}
```

i already have a program that listens to port 3015

Comment: it seems that the problem is when creating the socket CAsyncSocket::Create returns false; any idea why?

Comment: Isn't it possible to get an error code for Connect in MFC - I asume you use MFC here ?

Comment: i don't get compile error or runtime error. the program runs just fine. btw, i edit the source code above. the output is
0
0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized the socket using AfxSocketInit()? If not call it before you create the socket

Comment: an error occured if i do that. assertion thing. the options are abort, retry, ignore

Comment: CAsyncSocket is an MFC class read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12209/Socket-Programming-with-MFC-Part-1

Answer (score 0):

Connect() needs two parameters address and the length of the data.  The address is struct sockaddr_in which is passed to the method as SOCKADDR.  The length of the data is sizeof(SOCKADDR).

I'm not sure why most of the examples on the internet use something like Connect(ipaddress, port), maybe thats another SDK.

This connected for me:

```
if (AfxSocketInit() == FALSE) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to init sockets"));

    return _T("");
}

CSocket socket;
if (!socket.Create()) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to create socket"));

    return _T("");
}

SOCKADDR *sockaddr;

struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;


port = (u_short)(port);

// remote address
memset(&remote_addr, 0, sizeof(remote_addr));
remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", (&remote_addr.sin_addr));

sockaddr = (SOCKADDR *)&(remote_addr);
if (!socket.Connect(sockaddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR))) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to connect to server, 127.0.0.1 9000"));
```